# Table View in UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I want to display a few tables in my UWP application.
I couldn't find any good examples of how to design a table, as shown below, using either ListView or GridView.
[image: Table displacing some inforation]

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: What about using the [DataGrid from the Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)?

Comment: Yeah, I found the same after posting here.
Thank you